# How to move all files of a folder to another folder, preserving relative file paths, and overwriting old files?

Tags: files-and-directories

I have the following folder structure

```
Main
+updates
 +newversion
  +subfolder1
+subfolder1
```

I would like to copy the content of the subfolder "newversion" to Main, overwriting the content where necessary, and preserving folder structure/relative paths, so for example all files in Main/updates/newversion/subfolder1 will go to main/subfolder1. Is there a simple mathematica command to do this, or do I have to do an OS-dependent approach using execute and command line commands?

Comment: CopyDirectory["path/Main/updates/newversion", "path/Main"]

Comment: maybe I was not clear, I do not want to copy the folder newversion, only the files and folders inside it, and they have to go right into main. So I think I would need to rename newversion to main first, and then copy it with CopyDirectory["path/Main/updates/Main", "path/Main"]...but I see no option to overwrite content with copydirectory... is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first read the file names, then change the names to new names and finally do the copy:

```
names = FileNames[All, "path/Main/updates/newversion", Infinity];

CopyFile[#, 
FileNameJoin[{"path/Main", StringDelete[#, "path/Main"]}]
] & /@ names
```

Comment: this will include also folders in the list of names, probably giving errors with copyfile? Should I rather use somthing like Filenames[*.*,....] to filter folders?

Comment: The result of the command is a list of filenames, with an entry "Failed" where a directory name was given. Maybe that is not 100% clean, but otherwise there are no negative effects.